# Entity Framework Code First: How can I cast a set of entities returned from the database?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework-ctp5

I'm trying to figure out why this isn't working...

**DomainModel**

```
public class ModelEntities : DbContext
{
    public DbSet<Address> Addresses { get; set; }
}
```

**Controller**

```
public ViewResult List(int id)
{
    var db = new ModelEntities();
    var addresses = db.Addresses.Where(x => x.CustomerID == id).AsEnumerable();
    return View(entities.Cast<AddressVM>());
}
```

**View**

```
@model IEnumerable<WebUI.Models.AddressVM>
...
```

**AddressVM**

```
public class AddressVM
{
    public AddressVM(Address address) { Bind(address); }

    private void Bind(Address address)
    {
        // Mapping logic is defined here
    }

    public static explicit operator AddressVM(Address address)
    {
        return new AddressVM(address);
    }
}
```

Now, if I change the view to accept `IEnumerable<DomainModel.Models.Address>` and don't do the cast everything works as expected.

When I try and do the cast I get the following error:

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.Data.Entity.DynamicProxies.Address_37444C79F0AB1E0A599C8797F37448F12213C5BCAC0611B4C1C8EFADDEFAA82C' to type 'WebUI.Models.AddressVM'.

In the controller, why is `addresses` a collection of dynamic proxies even after calling `AsEnumerable()`? What do I have to do to get a collection of my domain model objects so that I can cast them to the view model?

Comment: Can you show the code for AddressVM?

Comment: Why do you think you will be able to just `Cast` a non-proxied `Address` to `AddressVM` anyway? The proxy is a red herring. The real problem is that you're trying to cast incompatible types.

Comment: Well I set up an explicit operator to do the casting. I didn't include that code for brevity but I guess I should have. I added the code for the Address view model. Does it make more sense now? I was under the assumption that a call to Cast() would enumerate through and cast each object in the collection using the explicit operator.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I bet your misunderstanding the concept of cast. A cast means the AddressVM instance is an Address instance... which i assume it's not. You will probably have to "convert" or instantiate the AddressVM object from the Address object. try this :

```
public ViewResult List(int id)
{
    var db = new ModelEntities();
    var addresses = from a in db.Addresses.Where(x => x.CustomerID == id)
                    select new AddressVM(a);
    return View(addresses );
}
```

*[edit] According [Brian's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5157170/entity-framework-code-first-how-can-i-cast-a-set-of-entities-returned-from-the-d/5157269#5157269), you can cast an object if there is an implicit conversion between your actual type and the target type.*

Comment: +1, but... Note that L2E supports initializers, but not parameterized constructors.

Comment: Thanks, your method does work. However can you please help me understand why calling .Cast<AddressVM>() doesn't? I have an explicit operator that converts from Address to AddressVM. Shouldn't the call to Cast() create a new IEnumerable of AddressVM and call the explicit operator on each address instance in order to populate it? Each AddressVM is created from an instance of an Address.

Answer (score 2):

You need to setup an [explicit operator](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/09479473.aspx) on your `AddressVM` if you want to be able to cast an `Address` to it.  You might take a look at AutoMapper if you want to move data from a domain model to a view model fairly easily.

Comment: Thanks but I did set up the explicit operator already. I just didn't include it for brevity.

Comment: +1 for Brian for suggesting the use of AutoMapper. @Terminal Frost, you're doing it all wrong. Try following clean design: separate your Domain Models from your View Models. Use AutoMapper to map between the two.